# Bionomial distribution - need help with calculating probability.

Tags: probability, random-variables

Suppose we draw a dice 300 times.
What is the probability to get '1' or '2' in more then 90 draws?

So $X\sim Bin(300, \frac{1}{3})$ ($X$ binomially [if that even a word] distributed with parameters $300$ and $\frac{1}{3}$), and we want to find $\mathbb{P}(X>90)=1-\mathbb{P}(X\leq 90)$.

$$1-\mathbb{P}(X\leq 90)=1-\sum_{k=0}^{90}\binom{300}{k}p^kq^{300-k}=$$
$$1-q^{210}\sum_{k=0}^{90}\binom{300}{k}p^kq^{90-k}$$
(where $p=\frac{1}{3}$ and $q=\frac{2}{3}$)

But now I'm not really sure how to proceed.
Is there a way to take the $\binom{300}{k}$ to the form of $\binom{90}{k}$ somehow, so I will be able to use the Binomial theorem?

Answer (score 0):

This is not very nice and i dont think there is an easy way to solve this but you can appeal to the normal approximation to binomial distribution.

See http://statistics.uchicago.edu/~s220e/Lect/lec11.pdf

Basically you treat your binomial distribution as a normal with the same mean and variance, and calculate the prob from that. Since your sample is very large, this is a reasonable approximation.